# horizontal scroller on tree panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4

does any body know how to show the horizontal scroller on tree panel...

since it describe [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?162989-TreePanel-no-horizontal-scroll-bar), the bugs will be fix in 4.1.x version,...
cause i'm not satisfied, i try to googling to find the hot fix,.
and i got [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?129320-TreePanel-scrolling-problem), Mr. Edspencer suggest to using ext 4.0.6....
but, it still not working,. ([tested](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammad_erdin/Uf7yy/) version 4.0.7)

anybody know how to fix this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some workaround. See code below.

```
afterrender: function() {
    var view = this.getView();
    var c = view.container;
    var e = view.el;

    var max = 0;
    Ext.each(e.query('.x-grid-cell-inner'), function(el) {
        el = Ext.get(el);
        var size = el.getPadding('lr');
        Ext.each(el.dom.childNodes, function(el2){
            if (el2.nodeType == 3) {
                size += 6 + el.getTextWidth(el2.nodeValue);
            } else {
                size += Ext.get(el2).getWidth();
            }
        });
        max = Math.max(max, size);
    });
    max += c.getPadding('lr');

    if (c.getWidth() < max) {
        c.dom.style.overflowX = 'scroll';
        e.setWidth(max);
        e.down('table').setWidth(max);
    }
}
```

You only need to add this listener to your `TreePanel`. Basically it finds width of wider element and extend width of table, switch overflow on container.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Uf7yy/2/